# How to add an icon in local task link ? (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal, module

I would like to add an icon in the local task links in drupal. Im a newbie..
I have already tried several solutions like :

```
 $local_tasks['entity.user.canonical']['title'] = '<i> class="icon--search"></i>';
```

With Markup:

```
$local_tasks['entity.user.canonical']['title'] = Markup::create('<i class="icon--search"></i>');
```

And also with an array...

But I found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to add icon.

1> We can preprocess menu local task.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) {
  $variables['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'nav-link';
}
```

Easy way is to use contrib modules like https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes

For Drupal7 this tutorial can help
https://www.webwash.net/how-to-display-icons-in-drupal-using-icon-api/